# Count of number of clicks does not update when I navigate back to homepage

Tags: java, android

I have a class in java and I have a  little issue:

I have a text view in my main activity that logs the total number of button clicks. Lets say the number is on 50 and I click on the funny stories button, I navigate to that page and the click count updates to 51 and I can see that within the text view for the second page.

When I press back button (a button I created) to go back to home page, the number in the homepage remains at 51. However if I go back to funny stories and clicks on so more buttons so that the count is on 60, this is displayed correctly in the text view within funny stories, but when I go back to homepage, the homepage click count still displays 51. How come it has not updated?

```
public int increaseClickCount() {
    int clickCount = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
    clickCount++;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, clickCount);
    editor.apply();
    return clickCount;
}

public int getClicks(){
    return sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
}
```

Here is the MainActivity class (homepage)

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(this);


            final TextView clickCountText = findViewById(R.id.click_count);
            clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));

Button funnyStoriesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_funny_stories);

funnyStoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));
                openContentPage("funnystories");
            }
        });

...
```

Finally here is the 2nd class where I select the back button:

```
Button backButton;
TextView clickCountText;
int getClickCountInt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);


    final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    clickCountText = findViewById(R.id.click_count);
    clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
    getClickCountInt = Integer.parseInt(clickCountText.getText().toString());

    backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write this line

```
clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
```

in onStart() of MainActivity